# Unrecognized element : 'binaryMessageEncoding'

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

For the below binding, I am getting an issue:

**Unrecognized element : 'binaryMessageEncoding'**

```
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ICCHttpBinding" openTimeout="00:01:00"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    </binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000" maxBufferSize="6000000" maxBufferPoolSize="12000000" />          
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
```

If I remove, 'binaryMessageEncoding' and try, it is raising:

**Unrecognized element : 'httpsTransport'**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set readquotas and use https, you could try

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingConfig"  allowCookies="false"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00"  
         closeTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" 
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"  />

      <security mode="Transport"   >

      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```